# Watchman crawl failed. Retrying once with node crawler

Tags: react-native, watchman

> Watchman crawl failed. Retrying once with node crawler. Usually this
>   happens when watchman isn't running. Create an empty `.watchmanconfig`
>   file in your project's root folder or initialize a git or hg
>   repository in your project.
>
> Error: watchman --no-pretty get-sockname
>   returned with exit code=1, signal=null, stderr=
>   2018-03-23T11:33:13,360: [0x7fff9755f3c0] the owner of
>   /usr/local/var/run/watchman/root-state is uid 501 and doesn't match
>   your euid 0

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're running watchman as root but the state dir, which may contain trigger definitions and thus allow spawning arbitrary commands, is not owned by root.  This is a security issue and thus watchman is refusing to start.

The safest way to resolve this is to remove the state dir by running:

`rm -rf /usr/local/var/run/watchman/root-state`

I'd recommend that you **avoid** running tools that wish to use watchman using `sudo` to avoid this happening again.

Comment: What about windows OS. I get this error on windows too.

Comment: you don't have the same issue as the OP because the Windows version of watchman doesn't have this same check.  I'd recommend that you reach out to the React Native folks for assistance.

Comment: Thanks. I got this error in Android Studio, and was running as root to upgrade the program. Closing Studio and opening again not as root seems to have solved it for me. I was building a React Native app.

Answer (score 247):

Testing with jest:

Step 1:

```
watchman watch-del-all
```

Step 2:

```
watchman shutdown-server
```

Comment: I tried all the solutions from the GitHub issue page but none of them worked. Then I came to the StackOverflow solution and its first answer worked. Thanks to its Trending Sort functionality and you @Jeffox.

Comment: This worked for me, on mac, but only after I first uninstalled watchman and then reinstalled it.

Comment: After OS updates on macos, watchman needs admin privileges to work again. `watchman shutdown-server` helped to ask the access to my documents and to have watchman working again.

Comment: The issue comes back after opening a new session, so the above commands, while they do make the warning go away, only work temporarily (running from inside an IDE)...

Comment: This command worked for me. I am on M1 Mac

Comment: For me as well, on mac M1 this command fixed it, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, this command worked and fixed it.

Answer (score 18):

As Jodie suggested above I tried the below and it worked well, for the benefit of others  mentioning below steps which I tried in my mac to fix this issue

1. First, Kill all the server running and close your terminal.
2. Go to 'System preferences' -> 'Security & Privacy' -> privacy tab
3. Scroll down and click 'Full Disk Access'
4. Make sure you checked on 'Terminal' and 'Watchman'.
5. Now relaunch terminal and simply try running again it works!!

Comment: Watchman isn't in the list there for me. Any thoughts?

Comment: Same, can't locate Watchman in 'Full Disk Access' - the watchman.rb file is greyed out when searching manually.

Comment: any updates on this? I also am unable to get watcman to show up in the list

Comment: to the people not able to locate watchman, go to the usr/local/cellar/watchman/22.XXXXX/bin/watchman

Answer (score 6):

1. watchman watch-del-all
2. watchman shutdown-server

Worked on MAC with no problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: help me, thank you!  was switching between 3 RN projects, and restarting watchman server fix this issue

Answer (score 5):

**-June 8 2022**

Giving Full Disk Access to all terminals or where you're getting started your server, is fixed the error.
Also, it would be good to give access (Files and Folders) to **VSC**.

### Here are the steps to do it!

1. Open System Preferences

[image]

2. Find **Security & Privacy** option and open it

[image]

3. Give Full Disk Access to your terminals, Xcode and VSC.

[image]

**Happy Hacking!!!**

Comment: Your answer can be improved by adding additional information. You should provide  step by step procedures to reach the "Full Disk Access" option and accomplishing the whole setting process. That would help much to anyone reading your answer.

Comment: Additional Step - On click Security & Privacy , Got to Privacy Tab .Scroll down to see  Full Disk access

Answer (score 5):

This error started to me when I ran the command `npx react-native-clean-project`, and with this step mentioned above, my case was solutioned.

Step 1:

```
watchman watch-del-all
```

Step 2:

```
watchman shutdown-server
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a real issue with this one but finally found the answer.

[Here's a screenshot of the post that helped me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7ejW.png)

https://github.com/facebook/watchman/issues/751#issuecomment-542300670

The whole forum has multiple different solutions which I hadn't actually tried, but this one is the solution that worked for me! Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this, on linux by using the following commands on terminal.

```
$ echo 256 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances

$ echo 32768 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_queued_events

$ echo 65536 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches

$ pkill node
```

Then:

```
$ npm start
```

or

```
$ expo start (if you are using expo)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
watchman watch-del-all && rm -f yarn.lock && rm -rf node_modules && yarn && yarn start -- --reset-cache
```

Comment: why would deleting your node_modules and yarn.lock help?

Answer (score 2):

If you're not actually using watchman with Jest just set `watchman: false` in your `jest.config.js` to stop this message when running tests.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: `$ npm cache clean --force`

Step 2: Delete ***node_modules***:  `$ rm -rf node_modules`

Step 3: `npm install`

Step 4? (Optional): `yarn start` / `npm start`

This worked for me. Hopes it works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

check for .watchmanconfig and add this {}.

Inside the file .watchmanconfig

`{}`

Simple as that just try it.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution is to kill watchman server by entering this command line in your terminal:

```
watchman shutdown-server
```

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, `remove all watches` and associated triggers of running process, then shutdown the service. See screenshot below:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put your project in a shared folder (ie, Macintosh HD/Users/Shared. I kept getting operation denied on the Desktop, because of further protection policies, even though Full Disk Access was granted.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue on my end, i had to stop the other node instance running on my other terminal. Just make sure you don't have another node running on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

### Watchman config file

I set my  .watchconfig  file to be extra permissible:
Add this code to your **.watchmanconfig** file

---

```
{
  "ignore_dirs": [],
  "fsevents_latency": 0.5,
  "fsevents_try_resync": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

// In jest.config.js, set watchmen to false.

```
module.exports = {
  //other options ...
  watchman: false,
};
```